# Removing an added handler to a separate control?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, events

I have a button control which requires adding a handler to its root:

```
     Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler( UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler( RootClicked ), true );
```

The problem is that when I do this the RootVisuual UIElement never destroys itself because of reference being created.

Is there a way for me to check when the RootVisual is no longer visible so I can dereference the event tied into it or at least in some other way dynamically remove the handle?

I've tried looking into weak events but the classes to implement that doesn't exist in silverlight..

With Weakreferences I've tried the following:

```
 m_clickEventHandler = new MouseButtonEventHandler( RootClicked );
 m_weakRefToRoot = new WeakReference( Application.Current.RootVisual );
 ( m_weakRefToRoot.Target as UIElement ).AddHandler( UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, m_clickEventHandler, true );
```

Comment: in what situation might the root visual not be visible. is this after the program is gone that its still not releasing memory?

Comment: The root visual is a login page, once the user logs in the login page should be deleted and it is deleted unless I've added the handler to it. So I need a way to remove the handler so the GC knows to reclaim the login page.

Comment: have you tried unsubscribing the handle in the unloaded event?

Comment: What is the unloaded event called? There is no unloaded in UIElement..

Comment: I'm using silverlight 3.5 where unloaded I think is 4.0 only.

Comment: it looks like the unloaded event is in the framework element which inherits from UIElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try mucking about with WeakReferences its a difficult thing to get right.  tam was on the right track, use the unloaded event.  True `UIElement` doesn't have such an event but your logon page will be something that ultimately derives from `FrameworkElement`.  Hence:-

```
 Delegate clickedHandler = new MouseButtonEventHandler( RootClicked );
 FrameworkElement root = (FrameworkElement)Application.Current.RootVisual;
 RootedEventHandler unloadHandler = null;
 unloadHandler = (s, args) =>
 {
      root.Unloaded -= unloadHandler;
      root.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, clickedHandler);
 };

 root.AddHandler( UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, clickedHandler , true );
 root.Unloaded += unloadHandler;
```

Comment: I'm stuck in silverlight 3.0 land which unfortunately does not have an unloaded event...

Comment: @meds: In that case you will need the assistance of whatever code that is re-assigning a value to the RootVisual.  Alternatively use a common page that is the root visual that contains a `Frame`  where you display the Login and then whatever else you would normally have replaced the RootVisual with.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.95).aspx

WeakReference is available in Silverlight 3,4.
Should be a solution for your problem.

Also, I am not aware of silverlight 3.5

Comment: I tried using weakreferences already but either I'm doing it wrong or it isn't solvign my problem...